# Using Annotations In JPA can I limit child records with a where clause?

Tags: jpa

I have an EJB with an @onetomany relationship like this in my parent class (Timeslot):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "rsTimeslots")
private List<RsEvents> rsEventsList;
```

I also have a function to get the rsEventList:

```
public void setRsEventsList(List<RsEvents> rsEventsList) {
    this.rsEventsList = rsEventsList;
}
```

This was all auto generated so far. In my view-layer code I can get a timeslot object and do something like `timeslot.getRsEventList()` and get all children of this timeslot. Now I need to restrict that list based on a criteria. For example I only want events that are children of this timeslot with a status of 1. Is there a way to do this with annotations?

Comment: If anybody has an updated answer to this post please do post it. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in JPA.

Normally you would execute a Query for this, using JPQL or the criteria API.

Some JPA providers do provide ways to restrict relationships, but I think you would be best off with a query, or providing a get/filter method on your class that just accesses the list and filters it (i.e. getStatus1Events()).

For an EclipseLink example of having a criteria on a mapping see,
http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/MappingSelectionCriteria

Comment: Arg. I was afraid of that. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: In the entity bean can I modify the get to remove the objects? Is this a bad thing to do?
`public List<RsEvents> getRsEventsList() {
        // remove any events without status=1
        List<RsEvents> eventList = new ArrayList<RsEvents>();
        for (RsEvents event: rsEventsList){
            if (event.getStatus()==(long)1){
                eventList.add(event);
            }
        }
        return eventList;
    }`

Comment: The accepted answer is from May 2011.  Is it still true for JPA 2.1 in August 2014?