# @JoinFormula and @OneToMany definition - poor documentation

Tags: java, hibernate, persistence

I have two questions concerning @JoinFormula and @OneToMany annotations:

1. How can I limit the number of result with `@JoinFormula` and `@OneToMany` annotations?
2. How can I define that `id` in expression `author = id` refers to `Author.id`?

   ```
   Author {

       @Id
       private Long id;

       @OneToMany
       @JoinFormula(value = "SELECT a FROM Article a WHERE author = id AND schedule < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()") // limit = 15
       private List<Article> pastArticles;
   }
   ```

Like this, I keep having the pastArticles empty, even when I remove the `schedule <` part of the clause.

Thanks!

Comment: For 2 you can't, don't know if 1 is possible. Maybe 1 is possible using an SQL query limit.

Comment: As for the limitation I found this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894931/onetomany-mapping-list-size-limit

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Answer 1 :

```
@Size(max=10)
private List<Comment> commentList;
```

Answer 2 :(just example like that)

```
public class A{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String uuid;

    ...
  }
```

other class

```
public class B{
      @Id 
      @GeneratedValue
      private Integer id;

      private String uuidOfA;



  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula=@JoinFormula(value="(SELECT a.id FROM A a WHERE a.uuid = uuid)", referencedColumnName="id")),
  @JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn("uuidOfA", referencedColumnName="uuid"))
})

     private A a;      
}
```

Comment: Some explanation would be nice.  I know that I am probably just too stupid, but I dont understand how  the annotations in Answer 2 work together

Comment: Perfect! I had to read multiple time your other class of answer 2. But once assimilated, I was able to fix my problem. Thanks a lot for your contribution!

Answer (score 3):

you'd be better off using the `@Where` annotation to limit the results