# How to filter the size of @OneToMany collection by a given criteria

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, jpa

Look at this simple example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "message")
public class Message implements Serializable {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long              id;

    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn
    private User              author;

    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    @OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
    private Set<Rating>       ratings;

    [...]
}
```

Is there any way to limit the size of `ratings` by filtering the collection elements. I want to load only those ratings, **which are not older than 30 days**.

In this way I load Message from database

```
public Message getMessageById(Serializable id) {
    Session session = _sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    return session.get(Message.class, id);
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [@OneToMany mapping list size limit](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894931/onetomany-mapping-list-size-limit)

Comment: @VladMihalcea it is not duplicate. I want to limit size by a condition

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finaly it works.

Solution:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
@Where(clause = "DATEDIFF(NOW(), date) <= 30")
private Set<Rating>       ratings;
```

From [Mysql docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff):

> DATEDIFF() returns expr1 − expr2 expressed as a value **in days** from one date to the other. expr1 and expr2 are date or date-and-time expressions

---

- I also tried the solution by [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29847797/1614378) but got exception:

  > Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '30 rating1_.DAY) and ratings0_.message_id=63' at line 1
- The solution by [StanislavL](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29845797/1614378) works, but only if you activate the filter:

  ```
  Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
  Filter filter   = session.enableFilter("minAge");
  [...]
  session.disableFilter("minAge");
  ```

Using `@Where` annotation is simpler because it does not require activation.

Answer (score 1):

Add @Filter annotation to your

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = { CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REMOVE })
private Set<Rating>       ratings;
```

Like this

```
@FilterDef(name="minAge", parameters=@ParamDef( name="age", type="integer" ) )
@Filters( {
    @Filter(name="minAge", condition=":age<= 30")
} )
```

See more [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/filters.html)

Comment: Note that this solution would work only if the JPA provider used is Hibernate.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the [@Where](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.5/api/org/hibernate/annotations/Where.html) annotation then:

```
@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
@OneToMany(cascade = { 
    CascadeType.PERSIST, 
    CascadeType.MERGE, 
    CascadeType.REMOVE 
})
@Where("time_created < NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY")
private Set<Rating> ratings = new HashSet<>();
```