# JPA: Limit number of rows in query invoked by find instance on joined tables

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have two entities

```
@lombok.Data
public class User {
  @Id
  private String userName;
  private String firstName;
  private String lastName;
  //Some more fields
  @OneToMany
  private Set<Attendance> attendances = new HashMap<>();
}
```

```
@lombok.Data
public class Attendance
  @Id
  private long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="userName")
  private User user;

  private LocalDateTime loginTime;
  private LocalDateTime logoutTime;
  //more fields
}
```

Attendance table is going to have record for each users attendance for each day. Over time, Attendance table will have multiple records for each user.
So a simple

> user.getAttendances()

will fetch all the records in attendance table for that particular user, which may cause memory consumption issues, and will also contain very old data that will have no significance in present day context.

What will be the best way here to limit number of records fetched by user.getAttendances() method to some configurable number e.g. 15 or 20?

I am using JPA repositories to query data.

Comment: I agree with some anwers in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7894931/onetomany-mapping-list-size-limit that it does not seem to be the intended use. Maybe use the parent id to query for attendances. You can use separate queries in the attendanceRepository with the intended parameterized count of results.

Comment: I agree with Andreas' comment. I would even go as far as eliminating the `attendances` property from the `User`. Rationale: since it makes no sense (just as you describe), why have it lying around (and always risk someone using it by mistake)?