# How to get First 5 elements Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have a very long object, so to make the system faster, I decided to show only the top 5 on "attendance" attribute (insted to show all the elements) when retrieve by the "get" service.

I have a attendances list, but there is a way to say only get the top 5 (on the list get) and when I got the results from the "detail" service, I will have all the itens.

```
@ManyToMany
private List<Attendance> attendance;
```

Comment: Are you using spring-data-jpa?

Comment: Im using spring boot (he uses spring repository)

Answer (score 2):

Write a custom repostitory, inject the entitymanager and use a query like that:

```
entityManager.createQuery("Select a from Enity e join e.attendence a")
             .setMaxResults(5)
             .getResultList();
```

Comment: I'm looking for same notation like `@ManyToMany(maxResult=5)`

Comment: @FabioPicheli I don't think its possible via annotation but I updated the answer with a join query which explicitly does the trick. For non jpa solutions look here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5858112/3698894.

Answer (score 0):

Even you can do by Hibernate Criteria:

```
public List findByLimit(Class persistentClass, String orderproperty, int limit)
    {
        Session session = getSession(); // Get Session here 
        try
        {
            Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(persistentClass);
            criteria.addOrder(Order.desc(orderproperty));
            criteria.setMaxResults(limit);
            criteria.setResultTransformer(CriteriaSpecification.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
            return criteria.list();

        }
        catch (RuntimeException re)
        {
            //Catch exception 
        }
        finally
        {
            //close the session
        }
    }
```

Now call the above function :

```
findByLimit(Example.class,id,5);  // here id is your order property
```